# spring bean properties with singleton

Tags: java, spring

Need clarification on spring singleton .I have three objects ,these are readonly so never changed values.

I am planning to create these objects with singleton bean as properties.

My question: When spring creates these objects,everytime it will create new object when   bean calls or once in life time it will call and create those objects?. What are the   possible threading issues if any?

Comment: Based on the singleton word meaning, it will create a **single** instance of these classes and return the same reference where need it. *What are the possible threading issues if any?* This will depend on your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you say to Spring to do. Spring has an Inversion Of Control container that manages the instances of the objects. Depending on the scope you give to your objects, it will make them singletons or not.

More info:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html